# linker error with hpp and cpp files added to a library

Tags: c++

I am using dev c++. also i am getting assistant from a library, developed by somebody else for my own c++ projects. i have added two new classes called `TriangleList` and `TriangleLists` to the library as i wanted new class types for the project. once, i added the hpp and cpp files to the library, i got the massage like `creating ../lib/libExtraction.a` . 
however, when i called back the functions, that i written in the new classes, from my own project, i got the error massages like

```
`[Linker error] undefined reference to `TriangleLists::Erase()`
```

(the above one for the Erase function)
then, when i removed the .cpp file and wrote everything in .hpp it works.

But, i would like to maintain two files for the hpp and cpp further. so, please tell me how to solve this link error problem as i want to learn this. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to check is if you're exporting the class:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) TriangleLists
{
//members
};
```

When you include the header in a different project however, you need to specify that the class is imported, so:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) TriangleLists
{
};
```

This is usually achieved with preprocessor directives:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_FIRST_PROJECT
#define DLLIMPEXP _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPEXP _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

//TriangleLists.h
class DLLIMPEXP TriangleLists
{
}
```

and only define `BUILDING_FIRST_PROJECT` in your first project. That way, when building the first project, you'll be exporting the class, and when you include the header in another project, you're importing it.

Second thing is that the other project must link to the `.lib` file generated by the first project.

The reason it works when you move the implementation to the header is that the method becomes `inline`, so there's no lookup for it in the `lib` files, as it's definition is already known.

Comment: i am sorry, i donot know how to do it as this is my first time using a library and adding classes to the library. (also i am using Dev C++). so, please tell me how should i do ur testing?

Comment: Actually, i have copied an existing hpp from the library and rename and then, wrote the functions on it. also for the cpp i did the same. sorry, i didnt do any exporting. any help please.

Comment: @user1199463 I don't know how to use Dev C++, but there should be some option in the project settings/preferences where you specify additional link libraries, where you need to add the library.

Comment: @user1199463 as for the second comment, I already told you how to specify that the classes should be exported.

Comment: :ok thank you for commenting. i will try to find the project setting and so on. thanks again.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, first, `__declspec` has double "`_`" symbol, than it is used _after_ class: like this: `class __declspec(dllexport) TriangleLists`

Comment: @Lol4t0 for me it works with a single "_". Also works with the _declspec before class.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, While my `cl` still works with single `_`, my `gcc` not happy with your code at all. Both compilers warning `ignoring attribute`, when it before `class`

Comment: @Lol4t0 alas, I did some research. You're right, I edited my question. When placed before the class, it only applies to the object, if you define one after the class definition. Thanks for that, I learned something new.